# Calculate element height the way slideDown() does

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have you noticed that by using jquery's slideDown(), even on elements with dynamic content, you always get the perfect height of the effected element. Which is, for me at least, impossible to do by simply animating the css height value. Mostly because there is no way for me to know how did the height of an element (with a display:none) changed, during a dynamic content (AJAX) update.

And since i've been working on some custom controls, i do need that capability to calculate things the way slideDown() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting a new dinamically loaded content, it means you have that element in memory, so you can refer to it and know its height. You only have to read its height (or maybe outerHeight) and slide by that amount.

**EDIT**

Just give a height of 0 to the hiden item and overflow:hidden, so that the content inside it won't be sohwn, and it will retain its height.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgyLm/9/

Comment: I just tried this, and it happens not to be  true. It seems that anything that resides inside an element with display:none has a height value of zero. If u have a different experience, please share an example.

Comment: display none was cinda important to me, but i guess i'll have to refactor the code

Comment: I don't know your complete code and structure so I don't know, but sometimes is simpler to just do like I suggest, or hide the element container somewhere (position:absolute;left:-99999px; for example) and then put it back to its original position. There are many other ways to achieve the same thing, expecially since you're using jQuery.

Comment: I actually finished the control the way you proposed and it operates perfectly - visually that is. On the other hand i really like how slideDown() works on display:hidden elements and slideUp() derenders the elements unlike our solution where everything stays put. Which is why i fear what would happen if things get crowded in the structure. I even tried understanding slideDown and slideUp in the development version of jquery - no luck :}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after appending the dynamic content to the element.

```
$(element).height();
$(element).outerHeight();//if you need margin to be included pass true to outerHeight method
```

Comment: what you meant is I calculate each dynamically added element's height before appending it to the animated parent?

Comment: I mean calculate the height after appending the dynamic elements.

Comment: check this example http://jsfiddle.net/jgyLm/ the dynamic elements in this example act like they don't have any height, just because their parent has display:none. how would you calculate height in such circumstance?